# cakephp installation 403 error

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, installation

I am trying to install cakephp on my webserver. I uplouded cakephp to my root directory and I am getting this 403 error:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access
>   /stud3/2012/user/www/app/webroot/index.php on this server.

The php version is greter then 5.2.8

I think it is something with .htaccess, in root folder it looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you given the appropriate permissions to app/tmp folder and app/webroot ?

Comment: You've literally posted the answer to your question IN your question (ie, you don't have permission to that folder)

Comment: I think permissions are good (755)

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite installed on your web server?